# Getting input shape mismatch error for predicting a label using a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Below is the code for creating and training the modal :

```
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(123, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(40,1)),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(7, activation='softmax')     # 7 - Number of output caategories
])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training :

```
history = model.fit(X, y.toarray(), validation_split=0.2, epochs=100, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)
```

Now I want to get the prediction by passing an audio file as input. I have coded as this so far.

```
# Extracting features from the audio file
def feature(filename):

    y, sr = librosa.load(filename, duration=3, offset=0.5)
    mfcc = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
    X = [x for x in mfcc]
    X = np.array(X)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, -1)
    print(X)
    return X


# Predicting the emotion
def predict_emotion(file):
    ftr = feature(file)
    prediction = emotionModel.predict(ftr)
    print(prediction)
```

But I am getting an input shape error :

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Highly appreciate your assistance for this !

Comment: What is the shape of the `ftr` variable and also what is the shape of your training data `X` ?

Comment: @darthbaba Shape of Training Data X : (5600, 40, 1) . Shape of ftr : (1, 1)

Comment: That's the issue, make `ftr` of the shape (40,1)

Comment: @darthbaba Both are 40,1 , but the error persists :(  "    Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
"